# Human body medical figure library/package?

Tags: diagrams, report

I recently went under a back surgery for a (double) slipped disk, S1/L5 which was operated, and as the second one (L5/L4) isn't so bad, it didn't needed any surgical attention so far; so I was wondering if there is a library or package with a human medical figure that allow to highlight the muscle/nerve pain I'm still having when the painkillers wears out.
My idea was to make a daily report on where the pain is located to help me explain to my doctor and physiotherapist, the evolution of my post surgical symptoms, in order to get the better rehabilitation therapy.

I would like to find something like this, but to be the background and to draw some lines, maybe using the TIKZ fill command to show it, maybe with 2 different colours to show the different tipe of pain, e.g muscular or nerves.....
[image]

Something that doesn't require a medical degree to call the different body part with their relevant medical name in order to highlight them on the diagram.

I typed some terms, but it's just a bunch of simplified human figures that show up, or answers on how to move the "body" of the text within diagram thing.....

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was surprised there is no "medical" tag.....

Comment: What you always can do is a) loading said image file, b) draw over it with Tikz. Here are a couple of ways to do it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz .

Comment: About a [medical] tag: what should it stand for? E.g. it's not directly related to LaTeX, and I haven't recognized "medical" questions before. However, there are quite a few: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=medical . So: what should it indicate?

Comment: I was thinking some other people used some latex to do medical diagram, I don't know, it seems so natural for me to use latex now for a lot of purposes.... Maybe some future physicians would use it for some report..... And this tag could make easy to find those topis.

Comment: Ok. When you inspect some tags for reference https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags ... what would you, what should users expect to find there about using such a tag? (Guidance etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using package `tikz-imagelabels`. It's built on `Tikz`, so you can also combine it with regular Tikz statements.

This package creates an internal reference scale, see grid example. Your image is saved as `human.png` in the doruments directory.

[image: result1]
[image: result2]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-imagelabels}

\begin{document}
 \begin{annotationimage}
%   [grid]              % comment this line out for no grid
    {width=10cm}{human}
    % ~~~ placing a label: x-coordinate predetermined by "left" ~~~
    %                      so you just need the y-coordinate
    \draw[annotation left = {neck at 0.8}] to (0.34,.82);
    
    % ~~~ drawing a thick line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[line width=3pt,blue] (.63,.76) -- ++(0,-.20);
    
    % ~~~ indicating a region ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[rounded corners, orange, line width=1pt] (0.3,0.38) rectangle (0.37,0.32);
 
 \end{annotationimage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpfull.